# JTextField object has an undersized highlight rect, and clips the text in Windows environment

Tags: java, fonts, jtextfield, japplet, clipping

For my Java applet GUI, I'm using JTextFields with a large, custom font that makes 7-segment digits.

The first problem I'm seeing is that when you mouse-down to select text in the box, the highlight feedback rect is undersized small on the bottom by 5 pixels.  What would cause this mismatch??  These highlight graphics are done by platform-specific code that is not accessible.  I don't see any methods in JTextComponent that access the highlight geometry.  It should match the bounds of the JTextField.

The 2nd problem is platform dependent text rendering.  In Windows-based browsers (IE, FF), the digits rendered inside the JTExtField are being clipped at the bottom by 5 pixels.  So, a "?" looks like a "7".  A "2" looks like a "7".  The text rendering works properly on MacOS browsers.  What could explain this weird dependency?

Hint: I'm using a custom 7-segment font that I downloaded from the internet. My applet downloads this font at launch-time from my web host...it is not depending on the font being installed in the system fonts.

Comment: SO is not a help-desk, but a Q&A site.  As such, each thread should be devoted to a single question.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Also, why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Acceptable workaround:   I went on the assumption that the bug was in the custom font design.  You can probe a font for its geometric properties using the Font and FontMetrics class methods (such as getDescent).
The descent was -4 which doesn't make sense for 7-segment digits, so I decided to correct the font geometry with an upshift of 4 pixels.   You define an AffineTransform that translates by (0, -4).   The Font method deriveFont(tx)creates a new modified font.   The digits are now clipped at the top --use the JTextField method setBorder() to open up additional headroom.